# jQuery Hover - Not Working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, debugging, hover

I have a problem with a jQuery Hover Effect, basically it's working perfectly in my version of Chrome and IE, and it is not working on Firefox.

It's very simple jQuery code, and I'm not seeing any reason why it's not working. Are there any good tools to debug jQuery?

http://www.ryansammut.com/jQueryHover.html

Comment: Please add the code in your site to this question.

Comment: add like this $('#shopNowButton')

Comment: @K6t - Thanks mate, was forgetting the ' for a moment. What tools do you use for debuginng jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the '#' in your selectors

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contactButton").hover(function() {
        $(contactButtonMenu  <---).attr("src","images/contactButtonHover.png");
            }, function() {
        $(contactButtonMenu   <----).attr("src","images/contactButton.png");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contactButton").hover(function() {
        $(shopNowButton   <----).attr("src","images/shopNow.png");
            }, function() {
        $(shopNowButton    <----).attr("src","images/shopNowHover.png");
    });
});
```

Comment: Works just by adding '#contactButtonMenu' instead of contactButtonMenu , Thanks :)

Comment: @RyanSammut cool :) btw, you can use firebug to debug the JS. It'll show that the events are being called fine. Just that the selector wasn't returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one document.ready.
Also the hover couldn't find the item he has to change (contactButtonMenu and shopNowbutton). try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contactButton").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","images/contactButtonHover.png");
            }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","images/contactButton.png");
    });

    $(".contactButton").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","images/shopNow.png");
            }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","images/shopNowHover.png");
    });
});




<img id="contactButtonMenu" src="images/contactButton.png" alt"Contact Button" class="contactButton" />
```

your alt tag is also malformed, change it to: `alt="Contact Button"` in the previous line

Comment: The hovering is fine, the effect you gave me is not the one I want, but thanks for spotting out the alt issue. Because what I need is on Contact Hover, the Hover of Shop Now get's switched off.

Answer (score 0):

replace it,

```
 alt"Contact Button"  =>  alt="Contact Button"
```

and I think this code is better..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".shopNowButton").hover(function() {
            $(this).attr("src","images/shopNow.png");
                }, function() {
            $(this).attr("src","images/shopNowHover.png");
        });
    });

    $(".contactButton").hover(function() {
            $(this).attr("src","images/contactButtonHover.png");
                }, function() {
            $(this).attr("src","images/contactButton.png");
        });
});
```

Comment: I want that the shopNow button turns off when the contact button is clicked, not just a Hover effect, thanks for your answer. However it is fixed not, with the 1st answer on this page.